# Handling "\" values CSV serde

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe

CSV serde unable to escape the values contains "\" in spark dataframe.

Reading CSV file data using spark CSV serde but it is unable to escape the "\" character.

spark.read.option("multiLine","true").option("delimiter",'|').csv("/data/working/dev01/textfile/")

Actual Result

_c1|    _c2   |*c3|*

----+--------------+

10  |"viv"|"1"|10  |

10  |"viv"|"1"|10  |

10  |"viv"|"1"|10  |

10  |"viv"|"1"|10  |

----+--------------+

Expected Result

"10"|"viv\"|"1"|"10"|

"10"|"viv\"|"1"|"10"|

"10"|"viv\"|"1"|"10"|

"10"|"viv\"|"1"|"10"|

Because of "\" it is merging two column values into one column.In above example "viv"|1 merged as 1 column as _c2,actually it should be

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before. And I'm not very sure what you want, but I can give you my similar solution(by using escape and quote options):

```
val df = spark.read
    .option("header","true")
    .option("escape", "\\")
    .option("quote", "\"")
    .csv("filePath")
```